# How to show the data with ngFor with defined html structure

Tags: json, angular, angular-material

I want to show first 5 datas in a json data in a div, which is located in the left and the rest datas in the other div, which is located in the right.

but it was not working.

the code just like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let data of jsonData; let i = index">
    <div
      class="content"
      [ngClass]="{ 'content-left': i < 5, 'content-right': i >= 5 }"
    >
      <ng-container *ngIf="data.state === 'Success'">
        <div class="state-success">
          <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="data.state === 'Failure'">
        <div class="state-failure">
          <mat-icon matTooltip="{{ data.message | translate }}">clear</mat-icon>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="data.state === 'Undefined'">
        <div class="state-undefined">
          <mat-icon matTooltip="{{ data.message | translate }}">clear</mat-icon>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <div class="message">{{ data.label | translate }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this jsonData Structure is just like this:

```
[
    {
        "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    },
    {
          "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    },
    {
          "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    },
    {
         "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    },
    {
          "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    },
    {
         "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    },
    {
          "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    },
    {
          "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    },
    {
          "state": "Success",
        "label": "hello",
        "message": "message"
    }
]
```

I do not know how to wirte this ngFor code.

anyone some suggestion?

Best Regards,

Leo

Comment: jsonData is an array? could you show us your ts file?

Comment: JsonData ist a Json Format  {{key: value}, {key: value}}

Comment: Is content-left && content-right classes are added correctly then it might be css issue. User pull-left && pull-right class which are default of bootstrap.

Comment: from my solution, I got by every first 5 items with content-left class, that is not what I  want.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Your `ngClass` expression might look like the following:

```
<div class="content"
     [ngClass]="i < 5 ? 'content-left' : 'content-right'">
```

You could use `ngIf`:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of jsonData; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i < 5">
    <!-- First five items -->
    ...
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="i >= 5">
    <!-- All other items -->
    ...
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Or using [`else`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else):

```
<div *ngFor="let data of jsonData; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i < 5; else list">
    <!-- First five items -->
    ...
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #list>
    <!-- All other items -->
    ...
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method in component and use

```
firstfive = data.splice(5, data.length);
allBesideFirstFive = data.splice(0, 4);
```

Than in create `ngFor` for `firstfive`  and `allBesideFirstFive`

Answer (score 0):

Here is working stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-ufayvp

```
<div *ngFor="let number of numbers; let i=index;">
  <div *ngIf="i<5">{{number}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="i>=5">{{number}}</div>
</div>
```

It's so basic, I hope it helps.

As @pzaenger mentioned in other answers, you can also use `else` condition as well.

Comment: I have update the structure my json data... can you update your example?